# Unable to log in with Jboss

Tags: java, spring, jboss, sas

Am getting the following error message in my browser, after installing RMfI (HF10):

```
HTTP Status 404 - /SASLogon/index.jsp
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
type Status report
message /SASLogon/index.jsp
description The requested resource (/SASLogon/index.jsp) is not available.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JBossWeb/2.0.1.GA
```

The URL has not changed from previously, so am sure this isn't the issue. Looking in the Services, I can see the Jboss server is 'started'..  What might be the reason for the above?

Edit:  I do notice in the services that SAS Remote Server keeps stopping:

[image]

Edit 2: Am getting the following error in C:\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\SASServer1\log\server.log:

```
2013-05-17 12:53:54,836 INFO  [STDOUT] ERROR [main] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Unable to return specified BeanFactory instance: factory key [config.context], from group with resource name [classpath*:beanRefContext.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config.context' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/SASServer1/deploy_sas/sas.shared9.2.ear/sas.shared.apps.war/WEB-INF/lib/sas.svcs.cluster.jar!/beanRefContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sas.svcs.cache' defined in class path resource [config-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.sas.svcs.cluster.SimpleCache]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to start distributed cache.
```

Comment: Is the app deployed? Do you see it deploying successfully in the server log?

Comment: Turns out there WAS an error in the log - see above..

Answer (score 0):

Did you install as an administrator?  Extract of installation notes:

*Note: If your Windows operating system is Windows Vista, Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008, it may be necessary to install with the “Run as administrator” option. Within the Start menu’s Accessories folder, right-click the Command Prompt shortcut, and select “Run as Administrator” option. Next execute F90009x6.exe using the -alwaysoverwrite option*.

Answer (score 0):

You deployment failed because dependency spring injected bean `com.sas.svcs.cluster.SimpleCache` failed to initialize. The root cause appears to be `Unable to start distributed cache.`

Looking up SAS documentation for this [issue](http://support.sas.com/kb/44/008.html), the root cause appears to be a specific `JDK 1.5 build SR9-SSU` on AIX servers. To resolve it you need to switch to `JDK 1.5 SR5a` build.

Comment: Thanks - I saw that issue, but Jboss is installed on Windows on my machine.  Does that fix still apply?

Comment: I do not know. Worth the try. Otherwise I would recommend you contact SAS support.